# Total Supply api for Coinmarketcap listing

Tags: api, rest, blockchain, solana, coinmarketcap

I'm looking at updating the Coinmarketcap listing for a token on the Solana blockchain.

For Total Supply Coinmarketcap asks to provide:

"API endpoint that displays ONLY 'Total Supply' as a numerical value (e.g. http://chainz.cryptoid.info/grs/api.dws?q=totalcoins)"

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have same problem did you solve it? 
need this solution for BNB token

Answer (score 1):

The `getTokenSupply` endpoint on the Solana JSON RPC will get you close: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokensupply

Unfortunately, it isn't a normal REST API endpoint, so it requires some parameters, and it provides JSON output.  In the output, you'll need the `uiAmountString`.  You may need to add in something to proxy the call and extract the value if CoinMarketCap is so stringent.